# Unable to start Simulator. Simulator crashed or cloased in Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, simulator

I'm developing WinRT metro app using Visual Studio 2013 premium version on Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 bit machine. After getting windows automatic update, I am facing following error while debugging my app in Visual studio.

[image: Unable to start Simulator]

Although, it starts the simulator and deployed my solution. But now, I am not able to debug my app using simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the root cause but following solution works for me

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete Temporary ASP.Net files
3. Delete VisualStudio Solution.suo file
4. Open Visual Studio and run the solution

Comment: Great but which temporary ASP.NET files?